# How I set another syntax inside a tag? With editor sublime text 3

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have difficulty understanding how to define a new sytanx inside a tag, I did not understand with some small examples.

I would like to modify the syntax HTML (Rails) with file .html.erb and what should I add code **to define a javascript syntax inside a tag `<% content_for :js do %>` until close `<% end %>`** ??

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I dont really get the question, but content_for is used to place some chunk of markup in another place for example: You have your in your html header definend <%= content_for: :js %>, so if you have a partial or other view you can set a block of code for that content <% content_for :js do %> alert("hello");<%end%> and when the processing of the view get done that alert will be placed on your html header.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT I do not understand your answer, my question refers to the syntax, that is, coloring the code in the editor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to make the code that is between `<% content_for :js do %>` and `<% end %>` highlighted like JS code.

In this case, you have to use `include: "scope:scope.name"`, like so:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
file_extensions:
  - test
scope: source.test
contexts:
  main:
    - match: "\\$.*"
      scope: comment.test
    - match: "<% *content_for :js do *%>"
      push: javascript
  javascript:
    - meta_scope: embeded.js
    - match: "<% *end *%>"
      pop: true
    - include: 'scope:source.js'
```

I use a context (`JavaScript`) for more clarity.

In the `main` context, the two first lines basically match comments (start with a `$`) just to check that the syntax was working. Then I check for `<% content_for :js do %>` and if it matches one, it **pushes** the context `javascript` (so it's going to stop reading the `main` one).

So, now, we're in the `JavaScript` context, the name I give to the scope is `embeded.js` (`meta_scope`), and then, if it matches `<% end %>`, the `pop: true` says: *stop reading this context, go back to where you were before*, so it goes back to `main`.

The last line is the line that tell sublime that in this context, we're using the syntax highlighting `javascript`.

Here's something to be aware of:

As soon as it finds a `<% content_for :js do %>`, the everything is highlighted, **even if there is no <% end %>**. The `<% end %>` just stop the sublime from highlighting the code using the `source.js` definition.

I hoped it helped you, if you have any trouble about this, you can find me on the [sublime text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/users/math2001/activity)

Comment: I use PackageResourceViewer for open resource, so I open Rails (HTML).sublime-syntax and add code, but not work, what is wrong? Code: https://gist.github.com/adrianoresende/f93ce3bd270a22a5b7e43d9385e0d7ed

Comment: did you extract the entire package, or just the file? I'm not sure that the file only could work. BTW, let's continue the conversation in your gist comments, so we get more room...

Comment: I edit file in path /Users/Foo/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Rails/HTML (Rails).sublime-syntax